# Ionic v3 live-reload on real device

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, livereload

Is it possible do live-reload on an actual Android device.  Currently `ionic cordova run android -l` brings up a web server port for live-reload, its on my device but its treating it like a browser vs a native app.  As a result, items like `window.plugins` and `window.cordova` do not get loaded into the server/browser live-reload which is causing me constant headaches.

I love the fast development feature of live-reload, but without `window.plugins` and `window.cordova` many aspects of my app are breaking - I use a lot of independent plugins not in ionic-native.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try [Ionic Devapp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/)

Comment: @Duannx Thanks.  I tried your recommendation.  But it too is not loading the `window.plugins` or `window.cordova`.  My code still errors out on those non-native plugins.  So far, the only way I seem to be able to those in my app is to load is to run it manually every time to the device.  Any other thoughts on how to get these two items to load in the `live-reload` or `serve -c `  ???

Answer (score 2):

I found the a solution on another forum.  Essentially you must copy the `cordova.js` file(s) into your root project `/www` folder.

```
3. Make cordova and plugins available
Copy the following from the viewer app’s platforms/ios/platform_www on the mac:
cordova_plugins.js, cordova.js + the two folders cordova-js-src and plugins and paste them into your www folder on the developement machine.

Thats it. Now you can do this ionic serve on your developement machine:
ionic serve -a -b -s -c -l --platform ios --nocordovamock

Then start the viewer app on your mac (or device). It should now load your project and automatically update when you save any changes.

When you are ready to publish your app you have to remove the cordova_plugins.js, cordova.js + the two folders cordova-js-src and plugins in your www folder before the final build.
```

There is some more detail at the original - for logging and other users input too: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-how-to-livereload-on-ios-and-android/50222